# Selecting 2 child elements after checkbox element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code structure:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name_1" value="some_val" />
<input type="text" name="input_name_1" value="xxx" />
<input type="text" name="input_name_2" value="yyy" />

<input type="checkbox" name="some_name_2" value="some_val" />
<input type="text" name="input_name_3" value="xxx" />
<input type="text" name="input_name_4" value="yyy" />
```

What Im trying to do:

On checkbox click Im checking is checkbox checked. If no then I disable first(child) and 
second(child) inputs. So Im stucked with JQuery code:

```
$("input:checkbox[name*=some_name_]").click(function(){
     if(typeof $(this + ":checked").val() == "undefined"){
       //disable two child inputs               
     }else{
       //enable two child inputs    
     }
});
```

So where I have commented lines that should be input text disable code. 
Im trying many variants but still no luck.

Any ideas ?

Your help would be appreciated.

**Edited:**

And what if I add some extra tags to my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" name="some_name_1" value="some_val" />
        </td>
        <td>       
          <input type="text" name="input_name_1" value="xxx" />
        </td>
        <td>   
          <input type="text" name="input_name_2" value="yyy" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How should I change JQuery code according to these HTML changes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){ // when the value changes, not just clicks
    if (this.checked) { // if the checkbox is checked
        $(this)
            .next() // select the next element
                .removeAttr('disabled') // enable it
                .next() // and the next one
                    .removeAttr('disabled'); // enable that one too
    } else { // otherwise
        $(this)
            .next() // select the next element
                .attr('disabled', true) // disable it
                .next() // and the next one
                    .attr('disabled', true); // disable that too
    }
}).change(); // trigger immediately to get the elements disabled if necessary
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDDMG/).

See the manual pages:

- [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)
- [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr)
- [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next)
- [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change)

---

Note especially the problem with this line in your question:

```
if(typeof $(this + ":checked").val() == "undefined"){
```

You can't concatenate an element and a string. Moreover, this is not the way to check if an element exists.  You need to do that by using the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length) property:

```
if ($(this).filter(':checked').length) {
```

or better:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

or, even better, per my above code:

```
if (this.checked) {
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the html up, you could try something like this:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
<input type="checkbox" name="some_name_1" value="some_val" />
<input class="textBox" type="text" name="input_name_1" value="xxx" />
<input class="textBox" type="text" name="input_name_2" value="yyy" />
</div>
```

Then for the javascript, i'd use jquery's context function.

```
$("input:checkbox[name*=some_name_]").click(function(){
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     if(typeof $(this + ":checked").val() == "undefined"){
       //disable two child inputs  
       $(".textBox", parent).attr("disabled", "disabled");
     }else{
       //enable two child inputs    
       $(".textBox", parent).removeAttr("disabled");
     }
});
```

Not the most elegant thing ever written, but i think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could see to achieve this is with:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).siblings('input:text').attr('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings('input:text').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VFEJq/).

---

**Edited** in response to @Alnitak's comment, below:

> this only works because you've changed the mark up

The following jQuery avoids that 'problem,' and works with the code as presented:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(    
    function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).nextUntil('input:checkbox').attr('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
            $(this).nextUntil('input:checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }).change();
```

[Revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VFEJq/1/).

Comment: @Alnitak, that's true. And the mark-up was changed because, to my mind, it required improvement. However, the *updated* [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VFEJq/1/) works with the html as presented.

Comment: sure - just thought it was worth pointing out that the posted JS was insufficient - you changed the HTML too.  Your new answer looks very similar to mine :)

Comment: @lonesomeday, I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. Clicking on the `$('input:checkbox')` triggers the `change()` event, though...

Comment: @David Your `change()` trigger doesn't trigger your `click` handler.

Comment: @lonesomeday, no, you're right it doesn't. Sorry; I think I misunderstood your suggestion. I...honestly hadn't intended that it should.

Comment: @David I thought you were intending the `change` to trigger the handler so that the input elements would be enabled/disabled according to the current state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that disables all input elements up to (but not including) the next checkbox, without changing the markup:

```
$("input:checkbox[name*=some_name_]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).nextUntil(':checkbox').filter('input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).nextUntil(':checkbox').filter('input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/7hSu7/